# jsPDF contents cut off issue with vue components and tailwind

Tags: pdf, vuejs2, tailwind-css, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to convert HTML components into a PDF.

Below is the code for that,

```
var doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'l',unit: 'px',format: [1250,1100],compress : true});
        let component=document.getElementById('document');
        doc.html(component,{
        margin: [10, 0, 50, 0],
        callback: function (doc) {
          doc.save("report.pdf");
        },
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    
        });
```

The resulting PDF looks like.
[PDF PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jowfw.png)
[image]

I expect jsPDF to move the component to the next page whenever its find that the size of the component is bigger than the rest of the current page.

Comment: can you explain more plz ? @KJ

Comment: im importing many  vue components , i've tried to upload the project in jsFiddle but i have many componenet and the project is big  @KJ can i contact u ?

Comment: any solution plz i'm stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. Adding in the "autoPaging" property and setting it to "text" should help. According to the [docs](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml) autoPaging set to text will "Trys not to cut text in half across page breaks. Works best for documents consisting mostly of a single column of text."

```js
 doc.html(component,{
    margin: [10, 0, 50, 0],
    callback: function (doc) {
          doc.save("report.pdf");
    },
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    autoPaging: "text",
    
 });
```